# How to get current localtime using Mysql and PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, time

I read from mysql website, I execute this:

```
SELECT CURTIME()
```

But then how to get the value? Using mysql_fetch_assoc()??

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you execute it as a normal query.  You might want to alias the column to a nicer name:

```
$data = mysql_query('SELECT CURTIME() AS the_time');
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data);
$theTime = $row['the_time'];
```

It's going to be more efficient to get the time through PHP rather than doing an expensive SQL query.

You can use the [`date()`](http://php.net/date) function:

```
$theTime = date('H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CURTIME() as time_now
```

***EDIT**

```
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");
$sql = "SELECT CURTIME() as time_now";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["time_now"];
}
```

Comment: Are you using classes? if not check greg's answer